# Mysql how to deal with JOIN and duplicate entries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an `articles` table which contains all articles.
I have an `comments` table with a field `article_id`, which contains comment for an article.

I first did my join query like this :

```
SELECT Article.*, Comment.* FROM articles LEFT JOIN comments As Comment ON(Article.id = Comment.article_id)
```

And had my data formatted like this :

```
Article1 Comment1
Article1 Comment2
Article1 Comment3
```

I then used group by :

```
SELECT Article.*, Comment.* FROM articles LEFT JOIN comments As Comment ON(Article.id = Comment.article_id) GROUP BY Article.id
```

And have my data formatted like this :

```
Article1 Comment1
```

I would like my data to be formatted like this :

```
Article1 Comment1
         Comment2
         Comment3
```

Is there anyway **with MySQL** to get my data formatted like this ? If possible, avoiding sub-queries ?

Comment: You better do that in your program logic and not in the DB layer

Comment: Why ? Data treatment isn't faster in MySQL ?

Comment: This is a representation issue and SQL is not designed for that. Select the data with SQL and do the rest in your program

Comment: So why functions like GROUP BY exists ?

Comment: If I had a table with 1 million row, isn't it faster to let MySQL format my data than do it in PHP with a foreach ?

Comment: To group your data. But you want to remove data where it actually exists (show article1 only once). The closest you can get easily is with `SELECT Article.title, group_concat(Comment.text) FROM articles LEFT JOIN comments As Comment ON(Article.id = Comment.article_id) GROUP BY Article.id`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59073/discussion-between-whitep4nther-and-juergen-d).

Comment: More of a heads up, to give us a working example, there is a thing called SQLFiddle, and it really helps. A lot of the times without knowing what we're theoretically working with, people post all types of answers. For Future Reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As comments have said, it would be best to do this in the presentation layer instead of the data layer. MySQL and other database engines are good at storing data, executing queries in the best way possible and getting you the results. There's not an easy way to do what you're asking for. Of course you COULD do something like this, but doing it in the front end would be much more efficient. I work with C# and SQL Server and I cannot think of a single case where I would do more than simply retrieve data with SQL. It's much easier to do processing with the presentation layer, whatever you may want to do. Your one comment asked about processing a million rows. Several of the tables I work with regularly have over a billion rows. I would still not do any of the formatting in SQL Server.

You asked what the GROUP BY function is for. Simply put, GROUP BY says put the records into groups where all of the columns in the GROUP BY clause are the same. One of the most common uses of GROUP BY is counting and aggregate functions (COUNT(), SUM(), etc). Consider the following query:

```
SELECT 
    Customer_Id, 
    COUNT(Order_Id), 
    SUM(Amount_Paid), 
    SUM(Amount_Paid) / COUNT(Order_Id)
FROM dbo.Sales
GROUP BY Customer_Id
```

In this query, we are selecting records from an imaginary Sales table. When we say `GROUP BY Customer_Id`, we basically saying "create groups and put all the records with the same Customer_Id in the same group". This is useful if we want to count the amount of orders the customer has placed (`COUNT(Order_Id)`) or if we want to see how much the customer has spent at our store (`SUM(Amount_Paid`), or even if we want to see an average of how much each customer has spent per order (`SUM(Amount_Paid) / COUNT(Order_Id)`).

This is just a simple example to show in basic situations how a GROUP BY works. It is not, however, designed for what you are trying to use it to do. It will eliminate duplicate records in certain cases (although `DISTINCT` may be easier if that's all you're trying to do), but it is not well suited for advanced formatting of query output.